# Possible to use a slice in a Sass map loop to start looping at the second instance?

Tags: loops, sass, each, slice, sass-maps

I have a map of breakpoints as follows:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 568px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1280px,
    xxl: 1500px
) !default;
```

And I need to loop over these, however I want to start the loop at the `sm` breakpoint. Here is my current loop:

```
@each $name, $value in $grid-breakpoints {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(#{$name}) {
        @for $i from 1 to 13 {

            .. stuff here

        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find one so far, but is there a way to adjust my opening line above to be something like this:

`@each $name, $value in $grid-breakpoints[2:] {`

Cheers

Comment: Why even have the xs?

Comment: It's a part of the setup for a client's framework. I, personally, wouldn't include it. But I don't wanna mess about with it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [map-remove](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_remove-instance_method) function, which take an [ArgList](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/ArgList.html) as second parameter.

[Demo (SassMeister)](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/eb0c0128cd3a010d41d175d97d71ce92)

```sass
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 568px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1280px,
    xxl: 1500px
) !default;


@each $name, $value in map-remove($grid-breakpoints, 'xs', 'sm') {
  .. stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check index number in your loop and if it is > 1 do something:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 568px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1280px,
    xxl: 1500px
) !default;

@each $name, $value in $grid-breakpoints {
  $i: index($grid-breakpoints, $name $value);

  @if $i>1{

    do something...

  }
}
```